# Rails 5 active record query where date range overlaps with other date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, activerecord

I have a model with `planting_date_begin` and `planting_date_end`.  I want to retrieve all records where any date in `planting_date_begin..planting_date_end` overlap with the range for the `current_week`

example:
if planting_date_begin: 3/5/2017 and planting_date_end: 3-12/2017
and this week is 3/26/2017-4/1/2017 it is not included in query.

if `planting_date_begin`: 3/1/2017 and `planting_date_end`: 4/15/2017 it would be included.

I set current_week range:

```
today = Date.today
days_in_week = today.at_beginning_of_week..today.at_end_of_week
```

This syntax is not right but I want to do something like:

```
Planting.where((planting_date_begin..planting_date_end).overlaps?(days_in_week) )
```

What is a succinct way to handle this?  Incidentally, I am using postgres in case there is a way to do it differently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe not as succinct, but I have to do this a lot in a current project and my method is...

```
start_date = Date.today.at_beginning_of_week
end_date = Date.today.at_end_of_week

@plantings = Planting.where('planting_date_end >= ? AND planting_date_begin <= ?', start_date, end_date)
```

This covers all overlaps.. if planting starts before the range and ends after the range, if planting starts during the range, if planting ends during the range.